# how can i pass dynamic values to url in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to give dynamic values to url which takes number of users and their age , which can be selected though web page. but I want to give it in `Jmeter` using `BeanShell PostProcessor`.
Help me in this,since I'm new to `Jmeter`.

This is the path:

> /destinations/packages?airports%5B%5D=LGW&units%5B%5D=000577%3ADESTINATION&when=29-05-2016&until=&flexibility=true&flexibleDays=3&**noOfAdults=2&noOfSeniors=0&noOfChildren=1&childrenAge=3**&duration=7114&first=0&searchType=search&searchRequestType=ins&sp=true&multiSelect=true

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for  your reply.I'm testing a web page for example http://www.thomsonprjuat.co.uk/destinations/ ,where I'm allowed to select number of passengers and age of the children. But the same process i want to do in Jmeter. I should be able to set the number of adults,children and their age in jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I've got looks like you can use CSV Data Set Config.

1. Create .txt file with the data you want to feed your test with;
2. Place the above .txt file to the folder where your .jmx file lies;
3. In your Test plan: Under your request sampler - place CSV Data set Config;
   [image]

Then if you need to use your dynamic values within one threadgroup => refer these data as *${quanity}*, *${age}* in you url.

If you need to pass these values across the threadgroups => add BeanShell Assertion
[image]

Then (in the other Tread group) refer those as *${__property(_quantity)}*,*${__property(_age)}*.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor), not Beanshell PostProcessor.
2. All this parameters are basically name/value pairs which can be defined via [HTTPSamplerBase](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addEncodedArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) class. HTTPSamplerBase class instance is available to Beanshell PreProcessor as `sampler` pre-defined variable so if you add the following code into the Beanshell PreProcessor "Script" area

   ```
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("airports[]","LGW");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("units[]","000577:DESTINATION");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("when","29-05-2016");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("until","");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("flexibility", "true");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("flexibleDays","3");
   sampler.addEncodedArgument("noOfAdults","2");
   //etc
   ```

   Your HTTP request will be populated with the values, you set via Beanshell.

JMeter Variables can be accessed via `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

```
String airport = vars.get("airport");
sampler.addEncodedArgument("airports[]", airport);
//etc
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive information on how to use Beanshell Test Elements in Jmeter.

Remember that it is recommended to avoid scripting where possible so if there is another way of implementing your task - go for it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is recommended to avoid scripting?